# Best way to do cumulative sum over binary encoded columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

I have written the following code to apply cumulative sums over several binary columns (grade levels for employees). It does so for each employee ID in a long format month-indexed dataset. However, it's extremely slow and results in NaNs. Any help is appreciated!

```
# Prepare
df = df.set_index(['Employee ID']) # index
grade_cols = df.filter(regex="Grade").columns # 1hot encoded grades
cum_colnames = [f"{g}_cum" for g in df[grade_cols]]
df[cum_colnames] = 0 # initialize

# Calculate cumulative sum
df = [df.loc[emp_id, cum_colnames].cumsum(axis=0) for emp_id in df.index]

# Sum into 1 column
df['Months in Grade'] = df[cum_colnames].sum(axis=1)
df = df.drop(cum_colnames, axis=1)
```

Example:

| Employee ID | Date | Grade A | Grade B | DESIRED OUTPUT: |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2022-01-01 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1001 | 2022-02-01 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1001 | 2022-03-01 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 1002 | 2022-01-01 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1002 | 2022-02-01 | 0 | 1 | 2 |

Comment: can you provide an example of input and the matching expected output

Comment: Your line for `for emp_id in df` indicates that it is an iteration over column names, not over rows. It may be wrong but it also gives me a difficult time to understand what you are trying to do. As @mozway suggested, please share representative examples of input and output in **text** form

Comment: Thank you, I have added a table with input and expected output (which should eventually be named 'Months in Grade')

Comment: What if there were a row for employee 1001, date 2022-04-01 and Grade A 1. Would the output in that row be 2 (1+1 for Grade A)?

Comment: I assume there can only be one column set to 1 per row? All other columns would be 0?

Comment: We have decided to simplify our dataset by aggregating per half year instead of monthly, greatly reducing the number of rows we need and allowing us to quickly code a 'time since grade change' variable. Thanks everyone for your input, though. I'm sure there is still a simple solution but I'm not concerned with it anymore.